# Mustache js causing failed to load resource error

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I have the following mustache js template :

```
{{#images}}
    <img src="{{.}}" width="10%"/>
{{/images}}
```

and am getting the below error in the console upon page load:

> GET http://localhost/base/url/path/%7B%7B.%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

Is it possible to prevent the browser from trying to load the image source within the mustache template until after binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem boils down to storing the template in the correct place, so that browser would not try to render it prematurely.

```
<script id="tmplt" type="text/template">
 {{#images}}
   <img src="{{.}}" width="10%"/>
 {{/images}}
</script>

<script>
 Mustache.render($('#tmplt').html(),mymodel);
 ...
</script>
```